# Should I add period after yes/no answer in survey?

Tags: forms, surveys, formatting, question-answer, grammar

Have you ever make a survey question with answers like

> Yes, with coke
>
> Yes, with beer
>
> No

With this kind of choices within a form, should you add a period after the answer? Or just leave it like above?

Comment: With a period, it is a sentence. Without it is just sloppy. I would even make it "Yes, with a coke".

Comment: I agree with @Hennes. "Yes, with coke" could give you unwanted attention from the police.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would address this as a bulleted list.

The Plain English grammar wonks have [clear guidelines on punctuating the bulleted lists](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/punctuating-bulleted-lists.html). According to them, your form qualifies as "a list of very short points" which do not need to end with a period.

Oxford Dictionaries agrees that ["if the bullet point is not a proper sentence, it doesn’t need to ... end with a period"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/bullet-points).

Answer (score -1):

Live it like above. Period makes sense when you have a complete sentence, when you express some thought or idea.

Comment: Period makes sense at the end of a sentence. Not only when you express an idea.